# firebase transactions you must return a promise

Tags: typescript, firebase, promise, transactions, angular6

I am trying to figure out how to write transactions to a firebase database from an angular 6 / typescript application.

One working example I am using as a guide is the following:

```
const transactions = [];

return db.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
            // const promises = [];
            descriptionsInDB.forEach(dbDescription => {
                if (dbDescription.matched === false) {
                    // item wasn't found, so add the item to the transaction.
                    const phraseItem: PhrasesDB = {
                        query: dbDescription.description,
                        updatedAt: Date.now(),
                        createdAt: Date.now(),
                        workflows: {
                            [workflowId]: true
                        }
                    };
                    const newPhrasesRef = phrasesCol.doc();
                    transactions.push(transaction.set(newPhrasesRef, phraseItem));
                } else {
                    if (dbDescription.data.workflows && dbDescription.data.workflows[workflowId]) {
                        // do nothing, this phrase is already part of the record.
                    } else { // update the workflows that are part of the record.
                        const workflows = { 
                            workflows: {
                                [workflowId]: true
                            }
                         };
                        const phrasesRef = phrasesCol.doc(dbDescription.dbId);
                        transactions.push(transaction.update(phrasesRef, workflows));
                    }
                }
            });

            return Promise.all(transactions); 
        })
```

The key pieces I’ve identified are as follows:

1) Create an array to hold your transactions: const transactions = [];

2) Begin the transaction: return db.runTransactions(function(transaction) {…

3) Execute a DB query using the transaction: transaction.set(newPhraseRef, phraseItem);

4) Push the transaction returned from the query to the transaction array: transactions.push(transaction.set(newPhraseRef, phraseItem));

5) Return a promise with the transaction array: return Promise.all(transaction);

If I have this right, then I should be able to apply this formula to the transaction I’m trying to write, and it should work:

```
        const pendingRef = `Pending/${req.query.inviteId}`;
        const acceptance = {
          'cryptoInvitationAcceptance': req.body.cryptoInvitationAcceptance,
          'reason': (req.body.reason !== undefined ? req.body.reason : '')
        }
return db.runTransaction(function(t) {
          const transArray = [];
          const docRef = db.collection('Pending').doc(req.query.inviteId);
          transArray.push(t.set(docRef, acceptance));
          return Promise.all(transArray);
        }).then(result => {
          console.log('result = ', result);
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log('err = ', err);
        });
```

But it always goes to the catch block and prints out the message:

err =  Error: You must return a Promise in your transaction()-callback.

But I AM returning a promise, aren’t I? The line: return Promise.all(transArray) is the promise I’m returning. No?

Comment: In the example you posted, the `transactions[]` are used to collect promises from the `forEach` loop.  This is why they use `Promise.all`. Since you are only doing one action, you should be able to `return t.set(docRef, acceptance)` without the `transArray[]`.  However, this shouldn't solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Please read the documentation for [`Transaction set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction#set) - it doesn't return a promise.  That's probably confusing the Firestore SDK, since you're returning `Promise.all()` of an array of things that are not promises.  So maybe it thinks you've returned an error.

You probably don't need to return anything at all from your transaction handler function.  Just call `set()` and be done with it.  You only need to return something from your transaction handler if you want to [pass that value out to the caller of runTransaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#passing_information_out_of_transactions) via the promise it returns.

BTW, in your first example, you shouldn't be collecting promises into an array that's defined outside the handler function.  That could cause problems if the transaction handler is run more than once.  As the documentation I linked to says:

> Do not modify application state inside of your transaction functions.
>   Doing so will introduce concurrency issues, because transaction
>   functions can run multiple times and are not guaranteed to run on the
>   UI thread.

That array outside the transaction would be considered "application state", since it's not inside the function itself.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Doug. I took out the transaction array and returning of promises so that it looks like this: return db.runTransaction(function(t) {const docRef = db.collection('Pending').doc
(

Comment: Thanks for the response, Doug. I took out the transaction array and returning of promises so that it looks like this: return db.runTransaction(function(t) {const docRef = db.collection('Pending').doc(req.query.inviteId); t.set(docRef, acceptance); }).then(result => {console.log('result = ', result); }).catch(err => { console.log('err = ', err); }); 
); ... but I still get the same error. I also tried returning t.set(docRef, acceptance). I also tried returning a promise after t.set(docRef, acceptance). I still get the same error. It's like db.runTransaction(...) can't be chained with then.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, this is the best way to do it:

```
      return t.get(pendingDocRef).then(data => {
        t.set(pendingDocRef, acceptance, {merge:true});
      });
```

The get(...) returns the promise it's asking for, so the set(...) doesn't have to.

I don't like this. I still think I should be able to do a set in a transaction on its own (i.e. without a get).

I also found that this *sort of* works:

```
return t.set(...).commit();
```

The commit() also returns a promise, but then I get really odd behavior: the transaction repeats itself over and over until it enters the catch block with an error to the effect of "transaction has expired." Nevertheless, the data gets committed to the database, so if you don't mind the error (just let it pass through), commit() works too.

See this post for details: [firebase transaction repeating when committing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52573212/firebase-transaction-repeating-when-committing)

Comment: I had the same problem, and I think it makes sense. You should load the current state of the document in a transaction before writing to it. Only that way, a transaction really makes sense, because if you don't, the document could have changed in the meantime.